# Getting visibility of a view without considering the child views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

So, I need to know if a view is shown. Generally I would use `isShown()`; from the docs:

> Returns the visibility of this view and all of its ancestors

But I have some child views which are not visible, so it shows me also for the root view that it is not visible. Same happens for `root.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE`.

I just want to know if the rootview (without considering the childviews) is visible, any ideas how to accomplish that?

Comment: `root.getVisibility()` supposed to return `true` if you haven't explicitly set the root visibility to `gone` or `invisible`. Post your layout.

Answer (score 0):

getVisibility assumes that if the target view is visible, then all of its children *may* be visible (without considering them individually for visibility).  And if it's not visible, it occupies space as if all its children were visible.  And if it's "gone", it has no effect on layout.

So I think you can use it as you're expecting.

Comment: But it is giving me back false even if the view is clearly visible.